# vim find lines with only 1 occurrence of quote

Tags: linux, vim

How can I find lines with only one occurrence of double quote in Vim?

I managed to find it by grep:

```
grep "\"" file|grep -v "\".*\""
```

but I need to get it on Vim. To be  able to modify those lines.

Comment: You need to get the result of your grep chain in Vim or to do the equivalent in Vim. Also, you should show us your actual command instead of merely talking about it.

Comment: Well, add it to your question, with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

### Grep in your shell, get the result in Vim

1. Make the output of your command more useful by adding the filename and the line numbers:

   ```
   $ grep -nH "\"" file | grep -v "\".*\""
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   file:7:lsytdlyusdtlsu"ydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   file:10:lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuodu"ystdosytslodyu
   ```

   See `$ man grep` for `-n` and `-H`.
2. Use Vim's `:help -q` and your shell's process substitution to populate Vim's quickfix:

   ```
   $ vim -q <(grep -nH "\"" file | grep -v "\".*\"")
   ```

   This creates a quickfix list…

   - through which you can navigate with `:help :cnext`/`:help :cNext`,
   - on which you can operate, item by item, with `:help :cdo`,
   - that you can display in its own special window with `:help :cwindow`.
3. Operate on each item in the quickfix list:

   This command:

   ```
   :cdo s/$/---hello
   ```

   would append `---hello` to each line with a single `"`:

   ```
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuodu"ystdo"sytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsu"ydtsuoduystdosytslodyu---hello
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
   lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuodu"ystdosytslodyu---hello
   ```

Alternatively, you can do the grepping first, and then do the following:

```
$ vim -q <(!!)
```

which will rerun the last command and pass its output to Vim.

### Do it from within Vim

```
:cexpr system('grep -nH "\"" file | grep -v "\".*\""')
```

which has the same outcome as step #2 above.

See `:help :cexpr` and `:help system()`.

### Operate directly on the matching lines

`:help :global` and `:help :vglobal` have similar semantics to `grep` and `grep -v`: the former marks lines that match and the latter marks lines that don't.

So, with `file` opened in Vim, doing the following should print the lines you are after because that's what `:g` and `:v` do by default:

```
:g/"/v/".*"
```

It doesn't *exactly* works the same but, in essence, it is the same logic as your grep chain: match quotes and then filter out multiple quotes.

Now it is up to you to decide what `<command>` to execute on the given lines:

```
:g/"/v/".*"/<command>
```

For example:

```
:g/"/v/".*"/s/$/---hello
```

would do the same as the `:cdo` example above:

```
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuodu"ystdo"sytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsu"ydtsuoduystdosytslodyu---hello
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuoduystdosytslodyu
lsytdlyusdtlsuydtsuodu"ystdosytslodyu---hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it, based on your comments

```
/^[^"]*"[^"]*$
```

This regexp will find a line starting with no double quote then one double quote then no double quote to the end.